# How `stdio` recognizes whether the output is redirected to the terminal or a disk file?

Tags: linux, c, stdout, write, stdio

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("If I had more time, \n");
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, "I would have written you a shorter letter.\n", 43);

  return 0;
}
```

I read that

> I/O handling functions (`stdio` library functions) and system calls perform buffered operations
> for increased performance. The `printf(3)` function used `stdio` buffer at user space. The kernel
> also buffers I/O so that is does not have to write to the disk on every system call.
> By default, when the output file is a terminal, the writes using the `printf(3)` function are
> `line-buffered` as the `stdio` uses *line buffering* for the `stdout` i.e. when newline-character `'\n'`
> is found the buffered is flushed to the **Buffer Cache**. However when is not a terminal i.e., the standard output is redirected to a disk file, the contents are only flushed when ther is no more
> space at the buffer (or the file stream is close).
> If the standard output of the program above is a terminal, then the first call to `printf` will flush
> its buffer to the *Kernel Buffer (Buffer Cache)* when it finds a newline-character `'\n'`, hence, the
> output would be in the same order as in the above statements. However, if the output is redirected to
> a disk file, then the `stdio` buffers would not be flushed and the contents of the `write(2)` system
> call would hit the kernel buffers first, causing it to be flushed to the disk before the contents
> of the `printf` call.

##### When `stdout` is a terminal

```
If I had more time,
I would have written you a shorter letter.
```

##### When `stdout` is a disk file

```
I would have written you a shorter letter.
If I had more time,
```

But my question is that how the `stdio library functions` knows whether the `stdout` is directed to a terminal
or to a disk file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` (of my specific libc) internally does a `newfstatat()` syscall on the stdout file descriptor (which is 1).

The kernel fills in the `st_mode` fiels with `S_IFREG` if it's a regular file you're piping into, and `s_IFCHR` if it's a character device (like a pseudo-terminal).

How I figured out:

```bash
gcc -o foo foo.c # compile your program
strace -o file.strace ./foo > tempfile
strace -o term.strace ./foo
diff *.strace #and look for things towards the end that concern the 1 file descriptor
```

Comment: `newfstatat()` is probably a Linux-specific name. The standard `fstat()` should do in most systems

Comment: @ilkkachu indeed, this was just an observation of what *my* glibc does – others, on other systems might do the same, but in a different way.

Comment: yep. And it's even possible the library calls `fstat()` (or `fstatat()`), just that the system call wrapper then actually calls a (newer) kernel implementation with another name. Somewhat similarly, `strace` shows a call to `clone()` (with a pile of arguments) even for a simple `fork()` call.